# Problems with nib-based/programmatically added UIViews hierarchy

Tags: ios

1.
I'm programmatically adding a UILabel to my view in the initializer and adding a gesturerecognizer.
Then I have other UILabels added in the IB nib file (and each of them also have a gesture recognizer)

I can see my UILabel on top but when I touch the screen the other (nib file UILabels) gesture recognizers are triggered.

I was wondering why, if I see my UIview on top, I can only interact with the views on bottom.

2.
-(void)awakeFromNib is never invoked. Why ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - is something over the top of your UILabels that has userInteractionEnabled = YES?  Do the UILabels from the nib have userInteractionEnabled checked?

2 - if you're using initWithNibName:bundle: awakeFromNib is not called.  awakeFromNib is only called if the object in question was stored IN a nib.  If you're using initWithNibName you need to provide that method in your class.

Comment: Damned userInterfactionEnabled, I always forget it. I see why awakeFromNib doesn't work. (But, is it supposed to work from a UIViewController in some circumstances ?). And yeah, I posted on apple forum as well :)

Comment: Do you understand the difference between storing a view controller in a nib, and creating one with initWithNibName?  Every object that is stored in a nib has awakeFromNib called on it when it is loaded.  If you are creating a view controller in code using initWithNibName, awakeFromNib will NOT be called.